# Need to get the last value of onChange for a slider React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, onchange

I'm using material ui sliders to get values before querying. Is there a way of only getting the values of the slider when it has stopped moving instead of every time it moves? I want to avoid using a submit button if possible.

Here is a link to the material ui demo, they use onChange to capture the values. I only need the values when the slider has stopped and not when it is changing.

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-sss3v

Comment: checkout `onChangeCommitted` from their documentation https://material-ui.com/api/slider/#props

Comment: Are you using hooks, if so then maybe [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/useifmounted-2s2ny) can help. You can set local state when slide change, create an effect that delays 100 milliseconds and then calls another onChange or dispatch if it's the last one.

Comment: Maybe you need `onChangeCommitted` - Callback function that is fired when the `mouseup` is triggered.

Comment: Sliding with arrow key would still trigger many times when using onChangeCommitted

Comment: I think a simple timeout is the way to go for this - very little code change to the example above and seems to do the trick IMO.

Comment: As of 2021 onChangeCommitted was renamed to [onChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/react-slider/isliderprops?view=office-ui-fabric-react-latest#onChanged)

Answer (score 4):

I might just do a simple timeout for something like this. You can just determine what you think is appropriate for when they have "stopped", after about a second seems to work okay.

````
export default function RangeSlider() {
  var timeout;
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState([20, 37]);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    timeout && clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('change');
      setValue(newValue);  
    }, 1000);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Typography id="range-slider" gutterBottom>
        Temperature range
      </Typography>
      <Slider
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        valueLabelDisplay="auto"
        aria-labelledby="range-slider"
        getAriaValueText={valuetext}
      />
    </div>
  );
}```
````

Comment: Also works, I prefer wrapping the logic in a special kind of Slider. Doing this stuff is called [debouncing](https://medium.com/@jamischarles/what-is-debouncing-2505c0648ff1) so I should probably rename my slider to DebouncedSlider.

Comment: My answer is technically debouncing I'm pretty sure and has all the performance benefit, just a simple implementation - I try not to get overly complex on SO - straight answers that address the question are generally better I think.

Comment: That works perfectly thanks for all your help. I don't have enough reputations to register an up vote but thanks.

Comment: Nothing wrong with keeping it simple but inexperienced programmers will likely just copy and paste the timeout in the handler and create duplicate implementation when they need to debounce another slider. Then the project code suddenly will not be simple anymore. Probably the best way to do this is something like [useDebounce](https://usehooks.com/useDebounce/)

Comment: @paulblackmore [Here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/304135/1641941) are some tips to get some quick reputation.

Comment: I'd say that's just a process issue on that hypothetical team of inexperienced coders. If you follow DRY, you will not do that and this is a whole other discussion - again, I try to keep answers on SO within scope of the OP, not getting into design patterns, paradigms, etc. Those are the SO rules...

Answer (score 1):

The only way to know if the user is done is to use `onChangeCommitted` but that only works when the user uses a mouse to interact. If the user uses arrow keys than `onChangeCommitted` will trigger for every change.

You could wait for a certain amount of time before doing the search. If there are multiple search term the user can change then you can use [useDebounce](https://usehooks.com/useDebounce/) demonstrated [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-j4576) code is in demo.js

```
const [search, setSearch] = React.useState({ slider1: 10, slider2: 10 });
const onChange = React.useCallback(
  (key, val) => setSearch(search => ({ ...search, [key]: val })),
  []
);
//start searching when user did not change anything for 5 second
//  I know it's a long time but demonstrates behavior more easily
const debouncedSearch = useDebounce(search, 5000);
// Effect for API call
React.useEffect(
  () => {
    console.log("user inactive for five seconds, going to search now");
  },
  [debouncedSearch] // Only call effect if debounced search term changes
);
```

If you do fire a request based on user input then you should make sure to only do something on the response of the **last** user input. You can do this with the effect and cancelled demonstrated in the code above and [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/useifmounted-2s2ny). If you don't you can get some unexpected race conditions.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the timeout approach you'll notice that your slider animation only updates at one second intervals. The best approach is to add the additional event handler `onChangeCommitted`. This way the value will stay updated on the slider.

```js
export default function RangeSlider() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState([20, 37]);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
      setValue(newValue);  
  };

  const handleChangeCommitted = (event, newValue) => {
      // Here will only be triggered once the user releases the slider.  
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Typography id="range-slider" gutterBottom>
        Temperature range
      </Typography>
      <Slider
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        onChangeCommitted={handleChangeCommitted}
        valueLabelDisplay="auto"
        aria-labelledby="range-slider"
        getAriaValueText={valuetext}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Note that if the user uses the arrow keys to adjust the slider, the `onChangeCommitted` handler will be called at every increment.